# PHP-remove double quotes in headers

Tags: php, css, csv

The code bellow produce a table from a csv file

```
 <?php
      $lines = file('graphdata/indicfortablevsprevious.csv');  


      foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
    $cellType = ($lineNum == 0 ? "th" : "td");
    $tokens = str_getcsv($line);

    if ($lineNum == 0) echo "<thead>";
    if ($lineNum == 1) echo "<tbody>";

    echo "<tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";

    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 300px;\">" . trim($tokens[0]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[2]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[3]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[4]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";

    echo "</tr>";

    if ($lineNum == 0) echo "</thead>";
}

if (count($lines) > 1) echo "</tbody>";
    ?>
```

The **1st table header** in the CSV is double quoted and the header in the php created table is also double quoted (Strangely the other headers are not). Is there a way to get rid of double quote in the PHP created table?

Comment: Is it possible that the source of those quotes is the csv file itself?

Comment: The ehaders in the CSV are:

"itemname","n2015Survey","2015Survey","2014Survey","Gaps Vs. Previous Survey"
Only "itemname" apperas double-quoted in the PHP table

Comment: Can you show us some of the csv raw ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using `trim($str, '"');` here `$str=header of first table`. try it it might work for you.